# Buildbot: Common buildsteps accross multiple factories

Tags: buildbot

So I am configuring buildbot builders with build factories, and have quite a number of them, and many of them use common build steps. What i currently do is:

```
f1 = util.BuildFactory()
f1.addStep(step1)
f1.addStep(step2)
f1.addStep(step3)
f1.addStep(f1_specific_steps)
f1.addStep(step4)
f1.addStep(step5)
f1.addStep(step6)

f2 = util.BuildFactory()
f2.addStep(step1)
f2.addStep(step2)
f2.addStep(step3)
f2.addStep(f2_specific_steps)
f2.addStep(step4)
f2.addStep(step5)
f2.addStep(step6)
```

This makes my master.cfg file go huge. Is there a way to do that more inteligently? Something like f1 = f_common_start + f1_specific + f_common_end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what you can do! Remember that buildbot's config is python code. So, using your example you could do:

```py
f_common_start = [ step1,
                   step2
                   step3, ]
f_common_end   = [ step4,
                   step5,
                   step6, ]
f1_specific_steps = [ f1_step_A, f1_step_B ]
f2_specific_steps = [ f2_step_Y, f2_step_Z ]

f1 = util.BuildFactory()
f1.addSteps(f_common_start + f1_specific_steps + f_common_end)

f2 = util.BuildFactory()
f2.addSteps(f_common_start + f2 specific_steps + f_common_end)
```

Basically you're just combining lists of Step objects. Also, notice that I'm using the `addSteps()` command to add multiple steps.

Here's an actual (shortened) working example:

```py
from buildbot.steps.shell    import Compile, ShellCommand, Test
from buildbot.steps.transfer import DirectoryUpload

clear_dregs = [ ShellCommand(command=["find", ".", "-name", "*.units.txt", "-delete"],
                             workdir="build"),
                RemovePYCs,
]
common_steps = clear_dregs + [
  ShellCommand(command=["cmake", "../src",] workdir="build"),
  Compile(command="make all"),
]

test_factory = factory.BuildFactory()
test_factory.addSteps(common_steps)
test_factory.addStep(Test(command="make test"))

docs_factory = factory.BuildFactory()
docs_factory.addSteps(common_steps)
docs_factory.addStep(Compile(command="make docs"))
docs_factory.addStep(DirectoryUpload(slavesrc="docs",
                                     masterdest="/opt/docs/"))

rpm_factory = factory.BuildFactory()
rpm_factory.addSteps(common_steps)
rpm_factory.addStep(ShellCommand(command=["make", "rpm"]))
```

Again, note where I use `addStep()` and `addSteps()`.